# Ansible: Removing gpg key on Ubuntu?

Tags: automation, ansible, devops, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to remove `apt_key` I added using ansible

- Adding the gpg key

```yaml
- name: Ensure an helm signing key is present
  apt_key:
    url: https://baltocdn.com/helm/signing.asc
  become: true
```

and this is what I want to do

- Deleting the gpg key

```yaml
- name: Ensure helm signing key is removed
  apt_key:
    url: https://baltocdn.com/helm/signing.asc
    state: absent
  become: true
```

- Output

`fatal: [master]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "key is required"}`

My question is, is there an ansible module way to get the `key` value or only using `command` to extract the value from `apt_key list`? any suggestion, please.

It will be very helpful for me if you include a code sample as well.
Thank you.

Comment: Hello @Hanoch, I'd just hard code the `apt_key.id` instead of extracting the string via `apt-key list`. If you do want to extract the string, I'd write an `awk` script to do that and store it in a variable and then use that variable in `apt_key.id`. Not sure if any of this matters as `apt-key` is deprecated. We have to move to the next shiny thing. Good luck,